# Move a point around a circular path

Tags: c, math

I have a point with 2D coordinates. I need to change the points coordinate values in order to follow a circular path.

How would I implement that using C?

Comment: You're needing to make the point travel the circumference? What increments of x and y? What radius and center-point? Is this homework?

Comment: `#include <math.h>` and use `sin()` and `cos()`. What have you tried?

Comment: Describe the path using polar coordinates.

Answer (score 16):

use sin and cos

```
for (double t = 0; t < 2*Pi; t += 0.01) {
    x = R*cos(t) + x_0;
    y = R*sin(t) + y_0;
}
```

where:

- (x_0, y_0) is the center of the circle
- R is the raduis

Answer (score 8):

Or in angle's instead of radians...

```
#include <math.h>

void Circle(float center_x, float center_y, float radius)
{
    float point_x, point_y;
    int ctr;
    for (ctr = 0; ctr < 360; ctr += 1)
    {
        point_x = radius * cos(ctr * 3.1415926f / 180.0f) + center_x;
        point_y = radius * cos(ctr * 3.1415926f / 180.0f) + center_y;
    }
}
```

Plots a circle around a center point, 1 degree at a time.  You can increment ctr by any amount to adjust the step size.

Comment: In the absence of **strong** reasons to do otherwise, prefer to use `double` in C. The floating point variables and constants in your code should all be of type `double`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use polar coordinates:

```
X = R * cos (phi) + center_X
Y = R * sin (phi) + center_Y
```

and change the phi in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you confused cos() for sin() for the y-axis. Code should be:
point_y = radius * sin(ctr * 3.1415926f / 180.0f) + center_y;