# Simultaneously move six points in circular paths around their own orbital centers

Tags: android

Suppose I have six points drawn in a `Canvas` along the circumference of a circle, in the pattern of a hexagon.

[image]

I want to simultaneously move and re-draw each of these six points in a small circular path - for example, each point moves along the circumference of a circle with 1/10th the radius of the larger circle.

I'm a little lost on how to do this with `Canvas` and `onDraw` and I don't know if better solutions exist. How would you do this?

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7437491/3558874) answers have at least pointed me toward this which shows how a point might move along a circular path, but I don't know how to implement it for this situation:

```
for (double t = 0; t < 2*Pi; t += 0.01) 
{
    x = R*cos(t) + x_0;
    y = R*sin(t) + y_0;
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

Start with a custom view that extends `View` and overrides `onDraw`.  You are on the right track with using the drawing functions of `Canvas`.

Give your custom view a field to hold the current angle:

```
        private float mTheta;
```

Then add a method like:

```
        public void setTheta(float radians) {
            mTheta = radians;
            invalidate();
        }
```

Then in `onDraw`, use the current value of `mTheta` to calculate the position of your points.

Of course, with the custom view you might need to handle sizing with an `onMeasure` override and possibly some layout with an `onLayout` override.  If you set the dimensions of the view to an absolute `dp` value, the default behavior should work for you.

Doing it this way will set you up to override `onTouch` and allow user interaction to move the graphics, or use a `ValueAnimator` to cycle from 0 to 2π calling `setTheta` from within your `AnimatorUpdateListener`.

Put some code together and when you get stuck, post another question.  If you add a comment to this answer with a link to the new question, I'll take a look at it.